# Functions random but text file always starts from beginning

Tags: python-3.x

Im importing read files into my function, i would like to random my functions but my read files are not following random.choice. Please help me figure this out, been working on it for days no help. How would you go about this?

```
## Program Name: 
## Date: 10/22/2015
## Developer: Arthur Winiarz

import random

QUIZ_FILE = open("Questions.txt","r")

correct = 0



def intro(start):
    if start == "yes" or start == "y":
        pass


def question1():
    global correct
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    ans = input()
    while ans == "A" or ans == "a":
        print("Correct")
        correct +=1
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect A is the right answer")
    return correct

def question2():
    global correct
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    ans = input()
    while ans == "T" or ans == "t":
        print("Correct")
        correct +=1
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect")

    return correct

def question3():
    global correct
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    ans = input()
    while ans == "C" or ans == "c":
        print("Correct")
        correct +=1
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect C is the right answer")

    return correct

def question4():
    global correct
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    ans = input()
    while ans == "F" or ans == "f":
        print("Correct")
        correct +=1
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect")

    return correct

def question5():
    global correct
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    ans = input()
    while ans == "B" or ans == "b":
        print("Correct")
        correct +=1
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect B is the right answer")

    return correct

def question6():
    global correct
    print (QUIZ_FILE.readline())
    ans = input()
    while ans == "T" or ans == "t":
        print("Correct")
        correct +=1
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect")

    return correct





def main():
    print("Do you want to start the Quiz?")
    start = input()
    intro(start)

    List = [question1,question2,question3,question4,question5,question6,
            question7,question8,question9,question10,question11,question12,
            question13,question14,question15,question16,question17,question18,
            question19,question20,question21,question22,question23,question24,
            question25,question26,question27,question28,question29,question30,
            question31,question32,question33,question34,question35,question36,
            question37,question38,question39,question40]

    random.choice(List)()



    print("You have",correct,"correct out of 40")




main()
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: inside my function, i have an open read file which reads the question for the quiz. however, when i try to random my list, the read file lines do not stay with the function block of code. They still show up in the same order as they are in the read file. How can random the function as a whole and make the correct read files stay within each function

Comment: i was also considering taking each read line from my text file and saving it as its own notepad file and labeling them and importing them that way but i wanted to try this way first, all out of one notepad document

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues. First is your use of `random.choice`. This will return any element from the list, but it will not remove it. Therefore, you might end up asking the same question many times.

Also, `random.choice(List)()` will only run one question once.

You can instead run:

```
# This will shuffle the elements of List, so that is in a random order
random.shuffle(List)
# and now we can simply run through each question in turn.
for question in List:
    question()
```

Now, you still have the issue of reading the lines in the right order. When you define a function in Python, the code block that is defined is not executed immediately. Rather, it is executed when the function is called. Therefore, if you call `question6` first, it will read the first line of the file. You can fix this by reading in the whole file at the beginning, and using fixed ranges to print the corresponding line in the function:

```
with open("Questions.txt","r") as QUIZ_FILE:
    QUIZ = QUIZ_FILE.read().split()
...
def question1():
    global correct
    print (QUIZ[0])
    print (QUIZ[1])
    print (QUIZ[2])
    print (QUIZ[3])
    ...
def question2():
    ...
    print (QUIZ[4])
    ...
```

and so on.